# Disabling concurrency check in EF Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I'm working on a system that crawls data and stores them in a SQL Database, and as you can already guess the data is fed to the db only from a single source which is my application. However, there are cases where I need to overwrite old data without caring about any concurrency conflicts. I guess Entity Framework by default has some concurrency check mechanism in its kernel as it throws the following exception from time to time:

> Data may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded

As I mentioned previously, I really don't care about this and I just want to push data into the db.

Is there any way to disable this in EF Core? To be clear, any way to define to the farmworker to just consider changes and push them in their place in the db?

Comment: this error likely is that entity object do not exit in your db table or EF no track object in get data from db...and right now you are trying to modify that

Comment: @AminSahranavard: Exactly the otherwise!

Comment: do you have a TimeStamp field or any fields with the [ConcurrencyCheck] attribute in your entity

Comment: @AminSahranavard: no.

Comment: concurrency is not your problem...
EF defaults to no concurrency control (last write wins) which allows lost updates.

Comment: The issue you are seeing is exactly what Amin mentioned: you loaded your entity from the db, then someone else deleted it or modified its primary key, and then, when you try to save, EF finds that no records are affected. There is nothing to "overwrite".